# Requires a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' after using `CrudRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, swagger

I don't know why but as I use `CrudRepository` in my Spring Boot Application:

```
public interface UserGroupRepository extends CrudRepository<UserGroupModel, Long> {
}
```

I'm getting this at the startup:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in 
springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider 
required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

I have no idea what SpringFox has to do with this but as I comment out `// extends CrudRepository ..`  things start working again.

Is Swagger interfering here with Spring Data?

See the [full auto configuration report](https://gist.github.com/silentsnooc/9c73f6dde4b2b386732dfbc525654a8e).
See the [full trace](https://gist.github.com/silentsnooc/4e2a46258fa144f331b61cc561770cb7).

---

The **pom.xml** I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <groupId>mahlzeit</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>api</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.0.M5</spring.boot.version>
        <hibernate.core.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.core.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Dependency Management -->

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- Dependencies -->

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Framework Boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL Driver -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Misc. -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Maven Repositories -->

    <repositories>
        <!-- Required since this is currently using Spring RC version -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: do youe have Swagger enabled in your project?

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes, indeed.

Comment: which version? and what is your spring-boot version?

Comment: @pvpkiran I'm using `2.0.0.M5` for Spring and `2.7.0` for SpringFox - I think those are the most recent ones.

Comment: yes. those are the latest ones. But the error is really wierd considering WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider doesn't take entityManagerFactory as constructor.

Comment: @pvpkiran Oh, that is indeed pretty weird.. But I can retry that as often as I want: The moment I implement that interface the application won't start. I don't know what Spring actually does when it finds something that implements `CrudRepository` but this is very weird ..

Comment: what is you use some other repository like Mongorespository or JPARepository? do you still get the error?

Comment: @pvpkiran I've tested `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` and `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository` - both give me the same error. I do not find `MongoRepository` in my current setup. Is this supposed to be available?

Comment: @pvpkiran Although, if this is dedicated to MongoDB then it probably fails anyway since I connect to a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159178/discussion-between-pvpkiran-and-displayname).